# How to change the output color of test-connection output

Tags: powershell, colors, output

I need to change the color of the text depending on the output of the `Test-Connection` -quiet cmdlet.

If true green and if False red.

I try to use write-host but without luck

```
$StartIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Start IP'
$EndIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input End IP'
$results=  ([int]$StartIP..[int]$EndIP) | % {"192.168.128.$($): $(Test-Connection -count 1 -comp 192.168.128.$($) -quiet)"}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: You are **not** using write-host, also output goes to a variable - where do you expect color to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your existing code:

```
$start = (Read-Host -Prompt Start) -as [int]
$end = (Read-Host -Prompt End) -as [int]
$start..$end | ForEach-Object {
  $ip = "192.168.128.$_"
  if (Test-Connection -Count 1 -Quiet -ComputerName $ip) {
    "$ip TRUE" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  else {
    "$ip FALSE" | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @TheIncorrigible1